# Equivalent of subclassing/interface in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Preamble: I'm somewhat new to Javascript. I'm currently building a game with CraftyJS (if it matters). I'm making something akin to an RPG.

I want to model a bunch of types of messages which can be specified to show to the user. These can be:

- A simple text message ([reference](http://www.trevorowens.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/first-image.png))
- A text message with an avatar image ([reference](http://img182.imageshack.us/img182/3135/sscaseru3.png))
- A text message and a bunch of choices ([reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTlQM.png))
- Possibly more types in the future

Under a language like C# or Java, I would probably choose to model this as a `Message` class (perhaps with fields for avatar/choices), or with subclasses, or as an interface for my specific message types to implement.

In Javascript, classes are structured differently. What's the correct way to model this? I see a few options right now:

- Anonymous objects with just a bunch of fields, eg. `{ text: "blah", choices: [ ... ] }`
- Some sort of class, eg. `new Message(text, avatar, choices)`
- *Insert option here*

Since my game is data-driven, users will be creating JSON (possibly by hand) and specifying message fields. A slight advantage of a class, is that I force users to specify all necessary fields in the constructor (although I can still validate messages without classes if I just use anonymous objects).

What are my options and trade-offs (or what design should I use here?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the message "facility" is open ("Possibly more types in the future"), then you may want to investigate a different approach:

Have a class for the user interface that exposes the appropriate methods to manipulate it, e.g.:

```
function MessageUi() {
    ....
}

MessageUi.prototype.setText = function(text) { ... }
MessageUi.prototype.setPicture = function(imgUrl) { ... }
MessageUi.prototype.setChoices = function(choicesArray) { ... }
MessageUi.prototype.show = function(callback) { ... }
// and so on
```

The message classes are required to implement a single method, say `render(ui)`. Example usage would be:

- For the simple text case:

  ```
  var msg = {
      render: function(ui) {
          ui.setText("My daddy used to hide...");
          ui.show(); // no callback; clicking just goes on
      }
  };
  ```
- For the choices case:

  ```
  var msg = {
      render: function(ui) {
          ui.setText("Maria! So nice to meet you!");
          ui.setChoices([
              {value: 1, text: "Yes, sir. Very nice to meet you...."},
              ...
          ]);
          ui.show(function(choice) { // callback gets selected choice
              ...
          });
      }
  };
  ```

As new types of messages are needed, the existing ones need no modification. You will only *add* methods to `MessageUi` and the new message types will make use of them.

Just some thoughts, this is not intended to be a "final" solution (the question is quite open ended). Have fun developing the game!

Comment: Just to be clear, you're advocating a single class with all relevant attributes?

Comment: For the UI. For the messages, any approach will do. If it is a one-time thing, just do it inline like in my code above. If the same message can be reused (simple text messages come to mind), or customized or has some complex behaviour, then a class for the message would be appropriate.